# My TOC headings are in Heading 1 style so this messes up figure caption numbering. What style can I use for TOC headings to avoid this?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

My TOC headings are in Heading 1 style so this messes up figure caption numbering. What style can I use for TOC headings to avoid this? Or is there another way to get figure captions based on chapter numbers (i.e. Figure 1.1, 2.1 etc.) to behave? I know that Heading 1 should only be used for chapter headings, but I want to use it for TOC headings so they appear in the navigation pane.

Answer (score 0):

### I suspect you are confused.

The headings that are used to create your Table of Contents should all be in your Navigation Pane. I can't imagine that you want the entries in your TOC to duplicate those entries again. That is what making your TOC *n* styles show up in your TOC would do.

Heading 1 text will appear, by default in Table of Contents. There is also a TOC Heading style built-in that is used as the heading for the whole Table of Contents. By default, that is based on Heading 1. If your TOC Heading style is not showing up in the Navigation Pane, make sure that it has an Outline level applied.

There are nine TOC n styles that correspond to the nine levels. These determine how your TOC entries appear in the TOC.

Here are links to some resources that may help you figure out what you need.

- [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [Creating a Table of Contents](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/tableofcontents.html) by Shauna Kelly
- [Why Use the Built-In Heading Styles](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm) by Shauna Kelly
- My page on [Outlining](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm)